# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function (Electron/ReactJS/Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm building cross platform desktop app using Electron and ReactJS with typescript. So there is a function like below. The functon is calling on a button click and it should print the text in the connected default printer. This is a third party library that handle the printing operation. But the problem is when i use this function, my app doesn't loads. it crashes.

```
function printcheck() {
        const printer = require('electron-print');

        app.on('ready', function() {
            printer.print("Text sent to printer.");
        });
    }
```

The error showing is TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function and error is pointing to node_modules/electron/index.js:7. I had used many other third party printing libraries also. everyone of those also crashing at this point.

```
function getElectronPath () {
>  7 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Providing the Electron version you used as well as a minimal example of the crash (e.g. with https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle) would help a lot with debugging the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the printing on the backend, which is Node. You can't do it in the front-end code.